# Unable to display Image from WebPage to android using JSON parser

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, imageview

I'm new to android, and woking on webservices that is parsing my web page data using JSON, followed androidhive json parser tutorial.. right now able to parse the title but not the Image, checked with logcat but even there no error. Feeling difficult to find the issue without error, Help will be Appreciated, Much Thanks

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
// Declare Variables
JSONObject jsonobject;
JSONArray jsonarray;
ListView listview;
ListViewAdapter adapter;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
static String TITLE = "title";
static String ALTERNATE = "alternate";


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from listview_main.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);
    // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
    new DownloadJSON().execute();
}

// DownloadJSON AsyncTask
private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        // Set progressdialog title
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android JSON Parse Tutorial");
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create an array
        arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
        jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                .getJSONfromURL("https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=json&id=APP_ID");


        try {
            // Locate the array name in JSON
            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("entries");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                // Retrive JSON Objects
                map.put("title", jsonobject.getString("title"));
                map.put("alternate", jsonobject.getString("alternate"));
                // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                arraylist.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, arraylist);
        // Set the adapter to the ListView
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Close the progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

SingleListview.activity

```
public class SingleItemView extends Activity {
// Declare Variables
String title;   
String position;
ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(this);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from singleitemview.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.singleitemview);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    // Get the result of rank
    title = i.getStringExtra("title");      
    alternate = i.getStringExtra("alternate");

    // Locate the TextViews in singleitemview.xml
    TextView txttitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rank);
    // Locate the ImageView in singleitemview.xml
    ImageView imgalternate = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.flag);

    // Set results to the TextViews
    txttitle.setText(title);        
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(alternate, imgalternate);
}
```

But when clicked on the ImageView getting NullPointer Exception.
Logcat Output

```
 02-04 11:47:28.078: E/AndroidRuntime(706): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to  instantiate activity   ComponentInfo{com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial/com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial.SingleItemView}: java.lang.NullPointerException
 02-04 11:47:28.078: E/AndroidRuntime(706):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
 02-04 11:47:28.078: E/AndroidRuntime(706):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
 02-04 11:47:28.078: E/AndroidRuntime(706):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
 02-04 11:47:28.078: E/AndroidRuntime(706):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
 02-04 11:47:28.078: E/AndroidRuntime(706):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 02-04 11:47:28.078: E/AndroidRuntime(706):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 02-04 11:47:28.078: E/AndroidRuntime(706):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
 02-04 11:47:28.078: E/AndroidRuntime(706):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 02-04 11:47:28.078: E/AndroidRuntime(706):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
  02-04 11:47:28.078: E/AndroidRuntime(706):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
  02-04 11:47:28.078: E/AndroidRuntime(706):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
   02-04 11:47:28.078: E/AndroidRuntime(706):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 02-04 11:47:28.078: E/AndroidRuntime(706): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 02-04 11:47:28.078: E/AndroidRuntime(706):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getCacheDir(ContextWrapper.java:188)
 02-04 11:47:28.078: E/AndroidRuntime(706):     at com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial.FileCache.<init>(FileCache.java:18)
  02-04 11:47:28.078: E/AndroidRuntime(706):    at  com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial.ImageLoader.<init>(ImageLoader.java:34)
  02-04 11:47:28.078: E/AndroidRuntime(706):    at com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial.SingleItemView.<init>(SingleItemView.java:17)
  02-04 11:47:28.078: E/AndroidRuntime(706):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
 02-04 11:47:28.078: E/AndroidRuntime(706):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
02-04 11:47:28.078: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
02-04 11:47:28.078: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
02-04 11:47:28.078: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Does your "alternate" attribute contain the path to image ??

Comment: thanks for the reply, i've updated my question please take a review @shree202

Comment: what is 'alternate'  in your code?????

Comment: alternate is the image @rajshree

Answer (score 1):

If you trying to retrieve larger images use `Namevaluepair` instead of `JSON`. If the image is around 50kb you can use JSON

Answer (score 0):

> I think you are going completely wrong.

First of all, your `ListView` will not be a normal `ListView`, but its a custom / customised.

For this, you need to prepare separate Adapter class that extends any of the Adapters (`Baseadapter` or `ArrayAdapter`).

Please refer to this link: [Android Custom ListView with Image and Text](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)